# How to override the style sheet of the react-native-calendar

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

Anyone know how to override the style sheet of `react-native-calendar` and implement a red `X` for marked days instead of `defaults red circle` background
https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars 
[image]

i want those red color circle to be a red cross

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the docs "Custom marking allows you to customize each marker with custom styles." I would guess you would replace the background with an image or svg graphic.

```
<Calendar
  // Date marking style [simple/period/multi-dot/single]. Default = 'simple'
  markingType={'custom'}
  markedDates={{
    '2018-03-28': {
      customStyles: {
        container: {
          backgroundColor: 'green',
        },
        text: {
          color: 'black',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
      },
    },
    '2018-03-29': {
      customStyles: {
        container: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          elevation: 2
        },
        text: {
          color: 'blue',
        },
      }
    }}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change MarkedDatas's 'selectedstyle' property.
example:

```
   markedDates={
                {
                  '2020-02-10': {selected: true, selectedColor: 'red'},
                  '2020-02-19': {selected: true, selectedColor: 'red'},
                  '2020-02-21': {selected: true, selectedColor: 'red'},
                  '2020-02-24': {selected: true, selectedColor: 'red'},
                  '2020-02-29': {selected: true, selectedColor: 'red'},
                }
               }
```